# Displaying Login Index When Project Url Types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

This may be a simplest question, but I am faced with the following issue.
I have a project, and have the login view at  http://localhost/Some.Web/Login/Index. If I type http://localhost/Some.Web/ I want to redirect it to login page. At the moment I am getting the "**The resource cannot be found.**" error message. My route config has the following entry.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

What am I doing wrong. Open to suggestions.

Comment: I hope you are not trying to authenticate users?, you can add `Authorize` at the top of your controller and `asp.net.mvc` handles that for you. Also, do you have a `GET` method `Index` in your `Login` controller?

Comment: @Bosco I have GET on Index method in Login controller and Authorize attribute on Home controller

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways you can set custom routes like `[routre("your route")]`

when you set this the add this in your route.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); to the routeconfig.cs file
```

and there is another way in your controller check if the user is authorize the redirect to that page other wise redirect to login page

```
if(userIsValid)
{
redirect("main page here")
}
else{

redirect("login page here")

}
```

Comment: I want to load the login controller index method, when a user types this url, "http://localhost/Some.Web" if the user is not authenticated, if the user is authenticated load the home controller index method.

Comment: For that use Session if the user is login then he can go to that page if he is not login then redirect to home page that's it